# Force Cloud Flare Flexible SSL on Wordpress with exception of feed

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

I'm using Cloud Flare Flexible SSL. i want to force SSL for all site except rss feed.

I've tried to do it with the code bellow but got ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

If your rss feed is an alias like yourdomain/rss just make the pagerule on Cloudflare side to not redirect to https:

```
Rule http://yourdomain* --> Automatic Https Rewrites - Off
```

On the wordpress side in the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/rss
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Clouflare will not redirect to https, but your Apache with wordpress will do.